# Splitting duplicates into separate table - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

In Pandas, I can drop duplicate rows inside a database based on a single column using the

```
data.drop_duplicates('foo')
```

command. I'm wondering if there is a way to catch this data in another table for independent review.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call the `duplicated` method on the `foo` column and then subset your original data frame based on it, something like this:

```
data.loc[data['foo'].duplicated(), :]
```

As an example:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1,1,1,2,2,2], 'bar': [1,1,2,2,3,3]})    
data

# bar foo
#0  1   1
#1  1   1
#2  2   1
#3  2   2
#4  3   2
#5  3   2


data.loc[data['foo'].duplicated(), :]
# bar foo
#1  1   1
#2  2   1
#4  3   2
#5  3   2
```

Answer (score 6):

[`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) has a companion method [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html).  They both take similar arguments.

The key arguments are:

- `subset` - column label or sequence of labels

  - Only consider certain columns for identifying duplicates, by default use all of the columns
- `keep` - {`‘first’`, `‘last’`, `False`}, default `‘first’`

When `keep` is set to `'first'`:

- `drop_duplicates` returns a dataframe in which the first occurrence of the combination of columns specified by `subset` is kept and drops the rest.
- `duplicated` returns a boolean mask indexed with the same index as the original dataframe with a value for True for all duplicated combinations of the specified set of columns except for the `'first'`.  You can use this mask to either get at the rows to be dropped or it's complement (the same as `drop_duplicates`)

#### Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list('abcdbef'), columns=['letter'])
df
```

[image]

```
df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')  # same as default
```

[image]

```
df.duplicated(keep='first')  # same as default

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool
```

Notice the row corresponding to the first instance of `'b'` is `False` while the second instance is `True` indicating it is to be dropped.

#### Answer

```
df[df.duplicated(keep='first')]
```

[image]

---

#### `keep='last'` and `keep=False`

Here are examples of what it looks like with the `keep` argument set to `'last'` or `False`

***drop duplicates***

```
df.drop_duplicates(keep='last')
```

[image]

```
df.duplicated(keep='last')

0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool
```

This time the first instance is `True` indicating it is to be dropped while the second instance is `False` indicating it is not to be dropped.

***just the duplicates***

```
df[df.duplicated(keep='last')]
```

[image]

***drop duplicates***

```
df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

[image]

```
df.duplicated(keep=False)

0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool
```

This time both instances are `True` and both are dropped.

***just the duplicates***

```
df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

[image]